# How do I split up a string with multiple parts and duplicate its rows in a dataframe with a prefix in python?

Tags: python, string, dataframe

Sorry I am unable to embed images to my post. Please see below for the images.

[image: From this Dataframe]

[image: To This Dataframe]

Here is the sample code:

```
names = ['United States', 'Australia', 'Japan', 'India', 'Russia', 'Morocco', 'Egypt']
dr =  [True, False, False, False, True, True, True]
car_number = ["FX00809", "FX00731", "FX00588,48,57", "FX0018", "FX00200", "FX0070", "FX0045"]
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {
    "country":names,
    "drives_right":dr,
    "car_number":car_number}
cars = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
print(cars)
```

I've tried to pull that row into a different dataframe and was able to duplicate the row using:

```py
df_multiple_car_number = df[df['car_number'].str.contains(r'^FX\d\d[,]', regex=True)]
m = df_multiple_car_number['car_number'].str.count(r'[,].*[0-9]$')
m = int(m + 2)
print(m)

#duplicate the rows
df_multiple_car_number = pd.concat([df_multiple_car_number]*m, ignore_index=True)
```

I'm having issues on how to split the texts and add the prefix "FX00" to the other car numbers.

Comment: If you are not able to embed images, this is to discourage you to use images for code or data, please provide **text**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning you start by dividing the column by commas to obtain a complete list then you can explode this series of lists. After move 'Country' and 'drives_right' to the index so that it's repeated for each element of 'car_number'.

I create another function to concat numeric value with prefix FX00.

So you can do like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def convert_splited_value(value):
    try:
        if int(value) >= 0:
            return  'FX00' + value
        else:
            return value
    except ValueError:
        return value
    
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country':['United States','Australia','Japan','India', 'Russia', 'Marocco', 'Eqypt'],
    'drives_right':[True,False,False,False,True,True,True],
    'car_number':["FX008093","FX00731","FX00588,48,57","FX0018","FX00200","FX0070","FX0045"],
    })


df1 = (df.set_index(['Country','drives_right'])['car_number'].str.split(',').explode().rename('car_number').reset_index())

df1.loc[:, 'car_number'] = df1['car_number'].apply(convert_splited_value)
    
print(df1)
```

**Output :**

```
         Country  drives_right car_number
0  United States          True   FX008093
1      Australia         False    FX00731
2          Japan         False    FX00588
3          Japan         False     FX0048
4          Japan         False     FX0057
5          India         False     FX0018
6         Russia          True    FX00200
7        Marocco          True     FX0070
8          Eqypt          True     FX0045
```

Comment: Is there a better way to set the index in (df.set_index(['Country','drives_right'])? What happens when you have a dataframe with many columns?